# Input channels equal to 6 on tensorflow

Tags: opencv, image-processing, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I need  to merge RGB and YCRCB channels, as the input data of retraining on tensorflow with mobilenet_1.0_224 model.

I changed the file `/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py` , in func `get_random_distorted_bottlenecks` :

```
bottlenecks.append(bottleneck_values) 

ground_truths.append(ground_truth)
```

to

```
bottlenecks.append(bottleneck_values)
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image_ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb)
bottlenecks = np.dstack(bottlenecks, image_ycrcb)
ground_truths.append(ground_truth)
```

and func  `create_bottleneck_file`, i insert :

```
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
image_ycrcb = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb)
bottlenecks = np.dstack(bottleneck_values, image_ycrcb)
```

before

```
bottleneck_string = ','.join(str(x) for x in bottleneck_values)
with open(bottleneck_path, 'w') as bottleneck_file:
  bottleneck_file.write(bottleneck_string)
```

At last, i changed the "mobilenet" input channel from `3` to `6`.

I thougth that now the channel of input data of mobilenet-retraining now is 6. I run retrain.py,
then got this:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): channels must be 0, 1, 3, or 4, got 6
>   °°Node: DecodeJpeg_1 = DecodeJpeg°acceptable_fraction=1, channels=6, dct_method="", fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1, try_recover_truncated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"§(_arg_DistortJPGInput_0_0)§§

How can I resolve it? Is it legitimately changing channel more than 4 ?

Comment: Edit the question to include a minimal, complete, and reproducible version of the code you are using.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar with multi-channel stacked image. The closest solution I could find is this tutorial, which I have not tried:

https://github.com/minhnhat93/tf_object_detection_multi_channels

Were you able to figure out how to do it?