# How to make tensorflow inception model work for image stack with input channels greater than 3?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am trying to re-implement https://github.com/jeffreyhuang1/two-stream-action-recognition (PyTorch ResNet) in TensorFlow Inception. While building a model for using a 20 Channel image stack, the code was straight forward!

self.model = resnet101(pretrained= True, channel=20).cuda()

Although, in TensorFlow there is no provision to modify the number of input channels. The work-around i could think of is to import the inception model pretrained on imagenet data (RGB, 3 channel) and add required variables to the the model graph to accommodate a 20 channel input. I do not know if this can be done in TensorFlow.

A similar question: [Input channels equal to 6 on tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918235/input-channels-equal-to-6-on-tensorflow)

and a tutorial, which was not very informative: https://github.com/minhnhat93/tf_object_detection_multi_channels

Comment: Do you want to do fine tune an existing, trained model such an inception model, or train a model from scratch ?

Comment: I want to fine tune existing model. All I need to do is replicate the weights in the input layer to suit a 20-channel image stack

Comment: Something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339355/how-to-modify-layers-of-pretrained-models-in-keras-like-inception-v3?rq=1 I would like to do the same with mobilenet on TensorFlow